# Browse Directories with text UI in Terminal

Tags: command-line

I remember there was a command that you can call in Ubuntu's terminal to get a very simple text based User Interface to go through directories. I believe you can call the command and then use your arrow keys to navigate directories. If anyone knows what that command is, or has heard of something similar, that would be appreciated!

Comment: use [ranger](http://ranger.nongnu.org/) another TUI file manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean a TUI [file manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_manager). I recommend [Midnight Commander](https://www.midnight-commander.org/), the command is `mc`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [midnight commander](http://www.midnight-commander.org), similar to Norten Commander. To install it, you shall look for the package mc.